# Windows Batch: error message when getting date

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2,3,4,5,6 usebackq delims=:/ " %%a in ('!date! !time!) do echo %%c-%%a-%%b %%d %%e 
ENDLOCAL
```

I want to simply echo the current date.
Instead, this message is output to the console:

```
The system cannot find the file 'Mon 06/29/2015 10:07:48.90.
```

What is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: missing single quote at the end

Answer (score 1):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2-6 delims=:/ " %%a in ("!date! !time!") do echo %%c-%%a-%%b %%d %%e 
ENDLOCAL
```

However, your script depends on Windows locale; for instance, in my locale should be:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:. " %%a in ("!date! !time!") do echo %%c-%%b-%%a %%d %%e 
ENDLOCAL
```

Consider locale independent solution based on next code snippet:

```
for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do echo set "_%%G"
```

Returns [`CIM_DATETIME` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
set "_LocalDateTime=20150629093247.246000+120"
::                  yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU
```

Replace `... do echo set "_%%G"` with  `... do set "_%%G"` no sooner than debugged. Then next code snippet displays `2015-06-29 09 59`:

```
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"
  echo !_LocalDateTime:~0,4!-!_LocalDateTime:~4,2!-!_LocalDateTime:~6,2! !_LocalDateTime:~8,2! !_LocalDateTime:~10,2!
```